# Chained RxSwift request with Realm add() / setValue()

Tags: swift, realm, observable, rx-swift, flatmap

Say I have 2 functions with 2 different `Observable` return types :

```swift
func getWatchedMovies() -> Observable<[TraktMovie]>
func getDetails(id: Int, language: String) - > Observable<TMDbMovie>
```

I'd like to flatMap each value in my `getWatchedMovies()` request to be able to request the details of each movie like this (I'm not sure it's the best way to do it though..)

```swift
 traktDataManager?
  .getWatchedMovies()
  .flatMap({ (traktMovies) -> Observable<[TraktMovie]> in
    let moviesObs = Observable.from(traktMovies)
    let movieDetails = moviesObs.flatMap { 
      self.tmdbDataManager!.getMovieDetails(id: $0.ids.tmdb, language: Device.lang) 
    }
  })
```

The thing is, I need to add each `TraktMovie` to Realm AND update a `TraktMovie` property, named `tmdbMovie`, with the nested request value of type `TMDbMovie` in Realm too.

What I mean is :

- first, I need to loop in my `[TraktMovie]` array to save each value of it in Realm (say an object named `traktMovie`)

```swift
for traktMovie in traktMovies {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  realm.write {
    realm.add(traktMovie)
  }  
}
```

- second, I need to retrieve the details of each `TraktMovie` object with the second request (e.g. `getDetails(_ , _)`) : with something like `flatMap` ?
- third, I need to update each `traktMovie` object property as follow with the value retrieved with the `getDetails` request (say `tmdbMovie` for the retrieved value):

```swift
traktMovie.setValue(tmdbMovie, forKeyPath: "tmdbMovie")
```

Here I have an object retrieved from the first request(`getWatchedMovies()`) named `traktMovie` and I update one of its property named `tmdbMovie` with the object retrieved from the second request (`getDetails(_, _)`) also named `tmdbMovie`

The thing is my first request returns an array and the second only a single object.

If I return the `TMDbMovie` object, I got only one object with `onNext` event and I loose my `[TraktMovie]` array.

Hope I'm clear enough.

Help is really appreciated !

Comment: I don't understand please add more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Observable.zip](http://rxmarbles.com/#zip) for this as in example below:

```
 getWatchedMovies()
        .flatMap({ [unowned self] (traktMovies) -> Observable<[TraktMovie]> in
            let movieDetails = traktMovies.flatMap { movie in
                // you can save in realm here
                return Observable.just(movie)
                    .withLatestFrom(self.getMovieDetails(id: 0, language: "")) { movie, details in
                    // here you have both movie & movieDetails
                    return movie
                }
            }
            return Observable.zip(movieDetails, { return $0 })
        })
```

It may be a bit risky, if one of *getMovieDetails* will fail it will fail whole stream, as well it will require all *getMovieDetails* to emit onNext event in order that zipped Observable to emit a value.

Comment: It allows me to request for the details of each movie but as you supposed, it fails after the request, I'm getting an empty response from target `getMovieDetails(id:language:)`. Is there something similar I can try that emits an onNext event even if the previous request returns nothing ?

Comment: You can add for details request `.ifEmpty(default: nil)` in case it completes with no value and in case of error you can use `.catchErrorJustReturn(nil)`. So you know if there is no value or request failed it will emit `nil`.

`self.getMovieDetails(id: 0, language: "").ifEmpty(default: nil).catchErrorJustReturn(nil)`

[RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#defaultIfEmpty)

Comment: This just works! Thanks a lot  I had to replace `nil` with a new `TMDbMovie` object as it was not compatible with return type but it completes the request . I was wondering though, should I have 2 subscriptions in my main function (e.g. `getwatchedMovies()`) or only one ? In your example you're using `self.getMovieDetails(_:,_:)` as if it was another function that already had a `.subscribe(onNext: )` after the request call. It's not what I did, just want to clarify this point here.

Comment: Yeah, to use `nil` you need to modify `getMovieDetails` to return `Observable<TMDbMovie?>`. 

As for the subscriptions, you definitely should go with one subscription. In my example there will be just one call to `subscribe`, it use flatMap in which you should return an Observable.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help and for clarifying your answer ! 